# JavaFX Scene loses color when a button is created

Tags: javafx, colors, scene

Can anyone explain why my scene loses color the moment I create a button in JavaFX?

The following code works, with the background of the scene changing to red

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    //Set Primary stage title and create a rootNode
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane();

    //Create a scene and add it to the rootNode
    Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode, 300, 200, Color.RED);

    //Add the scene to the stage
    primaryStage.setScene(myScene);

    //Show the stage
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

However, the moment I create another  control, like a button in the example below (and I don't even have to add it to the flowpane), the color reverts back to grey.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    //Set Primary stage title and create a rootNode
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane();

    //Create a scene and add it to the rootNode
    Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode, 300, 200, Color.CORAL);

    Button newBtn = new Button();

    //Add the scene to the stage
    primaryStage.setScene(myScene);

    //Show the stage
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Anyone know why this is? Am I trying to change the background color incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Your scene background color should not be visible at all, because `rootNode` covers the whole scene, and `rootNode` has its own background color which is set in the default JavaFx theme (that's the grey color you're seeing):

```
//modena.css

.root {
  ... 

  /***************************************************************************
   *                                                                         *
   * Set the default background color for the scene                          *
   *                                                                         *
   **************************************************************************/

   -fx-background-color: -fx-background;
}
```

So, you need to change the background color of `rootNode`, as the other answer already suggested.

The remaining question is why, in your first example, the default root background color is not applied to `rootNode` (it's transparent and it shouldn't be) and you see the scene's background color instead.

The answer - it's probably a bug. In JavaFx, the default theme is set with the method `PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet()` which is called only in these cases:

- when you call `Application.setUserAgentStylesheet` ([source](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/4f0addff16de7182752bc60541f44baeb0e99d2a/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/application/Application.java#L519))
- in static initializer block of `Control` and `PopupControl` classes ([source](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/4f0addff16de7182752bc60541f44baeb0e99d2a/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/Control.java#L99) and [source](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/4f0addff16de7182752bc60541f44baeb0e99d2a/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/PopupControl.java#L90))

`FlowPane` extends neither `Control` nor `PopupControl`, so JavaFx doesn't even load the default theme and your `rootNode` remains transparent (you see the scene's background color).

In your other example you create a `Button` control, which extends `Control` class, so static initializer block of `Control` class is executed and the default modena theme is loaded - your `rootPane` gets its default grey color from the default theme and you no longer see the scene's background color.

Comment: Note: I don't believe this behavior is a bug. The user agent stylesheet only styles controls, with the one exception being the background of the root layout. It makes sense to avoid parsing and applying a CSS file if the application never uses a control. The downside is this one relatively obscure issue.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Set the background color of the `rootPane` either to the desired color or to `Color.TRANSPARENT`.

This is a very curious case.

When you initially create the `Button` the `initialize` method is called in the Button's constructor:

```
private void initialize() {
    getStyleClass().setAll(DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS);
    setAccessibleRole(AccessibleRole.BUTTON);
    setMnemonicParsing(true);     // enable mnemonic auto-parsing by default
}
```

I assume (but I cannot tell you with 100% certainty) that <s>this applies styles to elements in your app</s> (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533014/2143225) it's because of a static initializer), because if you create a `Button` (and do not even add it to your `rootNode`) `rootNode` will have a background after the call to `primaryStage.show()`. To proof this I have modified your code:

```
System.out.println("background: " + rootNode.getBackground());
Button newBtn = new Button();
primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
primaryStage.show();
System.out.println("background after showing scene: " + rootNode.getBackground());
```

The output looks like this (and the background color is grey):

```
background: null
background after showing scene: javafx.scene.layout.Background@20c95282
```

If I remove the button creation and run it again the background color is red and I have the following output:

```
background: null
background after showing scene: null
```

So I suggest that you either set the background color to the `rootNode` or explicitly set the background color of the `rootNode` to transparent (`Color.TRANSPARENT`). Both solutions worked for me.

```
rootNode.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.CORAL, null, null)));
```