# Problem between scene background a a new Label in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, graphics, label

I'm approaching to develope a Snake Game with JavaFX (I'm benniger). 
In the main method I have set scene.setFill(Color.BLACK) and so the background is totally black. When I add a Label, when I try to instantiate it, the background disappear and the Label is not shown on the screen. 
It does not happen if I add Rectangle or Circle, but only with Labels, Buttons ecc.

How can I do to solve this? I think it is a simple question but I can not solve it by myself.

/Main.java

```
        GamePanel g = new GamePanel();

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        //Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400, Color.BLACK);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("SnakeFX");

        primaryStage.show();


        root.getChildren().add(g);

        g.requestFocus();
```

/GamePanel.java (I put only a part of the function initialize() that 
        is the first function of the constructor and that initialize the 
        gamegraphics and that must contain my label)

```
    void initialize() {     

    /* IF I PUT THIS LINE THE BLACK COLOR  ON THE BACKGROUND DISAPPEAR                                   
    AND LABEL DOES NOT APPEAR ON THE SCREEN.
     WITHOUT THIS LINE THE GAME RUNS PERFECTLY B BUT I NEED THIS LINE TO ADD 
        THE SCORE EHEH */

    Label l = new Label("TEST"); //this is the line 


    for(int i=0;i<WIDTH;i=i+WIDTH/40) {
        Line line = new Line();
        line.setStartX((double)i);
        line.setStartY(0.0);
        line.setEndX((double)i);
        line.setEndY((double)HEIGHT);
        line.setVisible(true);
        super.getChildren().add(line);
    }

    for(int j=0;j<HEIGHT;j=j+HEIGHT/40) {
        Line line = new Line();
        line.setStartY((double)j);
        line.setStartX(0.0);
        line.setEndY((double)j);
        line.setEndX((double)WIDTH);
        line.setVisible(true);
        super.getChildren().add(line);
    }
  ....
   ...
 .   .. 
    }
```

First image is without the instantiation of the label.
Second image is with the instantiation of the label (The background color is not shown and the label is not shown)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add your "application.css" file to your question? Thanks

Comment: it is empty. I have not used it. @DustinR

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Some part(s) of your code is missing. You're just instantiating a label which doesn't get added to your scene at all and therefore wouldn't change a thing. Please follow @Sedricks advice, and while doing it, you sometimes spot the problem yourself as you need to touch all relevant parts of your code in some way.

Comment: @Ignatiamus the problem is that. Also when the Label is not added to the scene it changes the background color. It is this the strange thing. I did not the label to ths scsne in order to show that the problem exists anyway, when I only have instantiated the label.

Comment: This sounds like some extremely freak error. Still, please try to get the problem down to a MCVE, see ↑.

Answer (score 0):

This is a JavaFx bug (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533014/10395952)).

What you see in your second image is the root node's (BorderPane) background color (which is defined in javafx default theme and it's not transparent). This is the correct state - the first image shows the bug described in the answer linked above.

You can fix your problem easily:

1. remove the background color from the root node, so the scene's background color becomes visible:

   ```
   root.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
   ```
2. or, set the root node's background color to black:

   ```
   root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, null, null)));
   ```

Comment: I solved that issue and now the scree  remains black but why can't I see the label anyway?

Comment: Have you added the label to the scene (`getChildren().add(l)`) and have you changed its text color to any color visible on black background?